# Collision Detection between two rectangles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, collision-detection

Fairly simple question that Im sure you will laugh at me for.
I have two rectangles playerRect and wall.
I have an if statement with the condition being  ..

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect,wall)) {
      //handle collision here
}
```

The problem I'm having is working out which side actually hit the wall rectangle.
I need to know because then I stop te player from moving depending on which side hit.
Thanks for any help
Disco

Comment: check this if u didn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079168/collision-detection-2d-between-rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add some direction property to my 'Player' object. This way when you detect a collision, you just check to see which way the player was moving prior to the collision and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CGRect for each side of your object with just a width of 1 (or height of 1 depending on the side) and look for intersections with the sides instead of the entire object. If your object is moving faster than 1 pixel per collision check, then you would check the sides **in addition to** checking the entire object