# Bullet Collision Detection

Tags: android, box2d, sprite, andengine, bullet

I'm developing a game by andengine.I have player.And there are enemies that are coming random time with MoveModifier and they are sprite.I want: The plyer shoot a bullet and the bullet touch enemy, the enemy will be invisible.How can I do?

Bullet

```
  private Runnable mStartCircle1 = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                final Scene scene= HelicopterActivity.this.mEngine.getScene();



                 float velocityOfCircleC=1.6f;
                    float startXC=player.getX()+50;
                    float finishXC=800;
                    float startYC=player.getY()+15;
                    float finishYC=startYC;

                    bullet=new Sprite(startXC, startYC, HelicopterActivity.this.gasTextureRegion);
                    bullet.registerEntityModifier(
                            (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                                    new MoveModifier(velocityOfCircleC, bullet.getX(),  finishXC, bullet.getY(), finishYC)));

                    scene.attachChild(bullet);
```

Enemy

```
      int j=0, k=0;
    private Runnable mStartCircle = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final Scene scene= HelicopterActivity.this.mEngine.getScene();

            float startY=randomNumber.nextInt(670 - 1); 
            float velocityOfCircle=6;
            enemy[j] = new Sprite( 800, startY, HelicopterActivity.this.enemyTextureRegion);
            enemy[j].registerEntityModifier(
                    (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                                new MoveModifier(velocityOfCircle, enemy[j].getX(),  -128, 
                                        enemy[j].getY(), enemy[j].getY())));
            scene.attachChild(enemy[j]);

            float startY2=randomNumber.nextInt(670 - 1); 
            float velocityOfCircle2=10;
            enemy2[k] = new Sprite( 800, startY2, HelicopterActivity.this.enemy2TextureRegion);
            enemy2[k].registerEntityModifier(
                    (IEntityModifier) new SequenceEntityModifier (
                                new MoveModifier(velocityOfCircle2, enemy2[k].getX(),  -128, 
                                        enemy2[k].getY(), enemy2[k].getY())));
            scene.attachChild(enemy2[k]);






            k++;
            j++;

            if (k<50){
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStartCircle,5000);
            } 

     }};


                if (i<1000){
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mStartCircle1,1000);
                } 

         }};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is similar game to yours.. in these examples is collision detection example:

[Simple android game tutotrial using andengine](http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/)

[Improved version of the game](http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/simple-andengine-game-v2-0-more-awesomeness/)

Answer (score 1):

One way to detect collision is to treat bullet and enemy both as rectangles and detect whether rectangles are colliding or not, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079168/collision-detection-2d-between-rectangles) to know how to detect collision between the rectangles.

otherwise, check out [this](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/) tutorial to know how to detect collision between two bodies of any shape.